# bsxfun implementation in matrix multiplication

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, bsxfun

As always trying to learn more from you, I was hoping I could receive some help with the following code.

I need to accomplish the following:

1) I have a vector:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
```

2) and a matrix:

```
A =[11    14    1
    5     8    18
    10    8    19
    13    20   16]
```

I need to be able to multiply `each` value from `x` with `every` value of `A`, this means:

```
new_matrix = [1* A
              2* A
              3* A
               ...
              12* A]
```

This will give me this `new_matrix` of size `(12*m x n)` assuming `A (mxn)`. And in this case `(12*4x3)`

How can I do this using `bsxfun` from matlab? and, would this method be faster than a `for-loop`?

Regarding my `for-loop`, I need some help here as well... I am not able to storage each `"new_matrix"` as the loop runs :(

```
for i=x
new_matrix = A.*x(i)
end
```

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT: After the solutions where given**

**First solution**

```
clear all
clc
x=1:0.1:50;
A = rand(1000,1000);
tic
val = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(x,[3 1 2]));
out = reshape(permute(val,[1 3 2]),size(val,1)*size(val,3),[]);
toc
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 7.597939 seconds.
```

**Second solution**

```
clear all
clc
x=1:0.1:50;
A = rand(1000,1000);
tic
Ps = kron(x.',A);
toc
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 48.445417 seconds.
```

Comment: The for-loop can be accomplished by predefining your `new_matrix` in size of `(12*m,n)` as you said yourself and then using indices to tell your `new_matrix` where you want these elements saved, e.g. in your code given above `new_matrix(((i-1)*12+1):(i*12))) = A.*x(i)` i wrote it just here, so not sure if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Minion, I'll check if it works and I'll let you know!

Comment: @Minion It works just almost, I get something in between the `1*new_matrix`, `2*new_matrix` `3*new_matrix` ...etc some other calculations which I can't tell where they come from.

Comment: @SergioHaram Thank you for posting this question! Hopefully this will come handy for people interested in `bsxfun`.

Comment: Kool! Some benchmarks results!! Thanks for posting those!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Send `x` to the third dimension, so that singleton expansion would come into effect when `bsxfun` is used for multiplication with `A`, extending the product result to the third dimension. Then, perform the `bsxfun` multiplication -

```
val = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(x,[3 1 2]))
```

Now, `val` is a `3D` matrix and the desired output is expected to be a `2D` matrix concatenated along the columns through the third dimension. This is achieved below -

```
out = reshape(permute(val,[1 3 2]),size(val,1)*size(val,3),[])
```

Hope that made sense! Spread the `bsxfun` word around! woo!! :)

Comment: This should be working quite well. At least it did for my test. But i don't really understand the code. Why the permutate? Would you mind to edit your answer and explain it a bit?

Comment: Thanks @Divakar :D again!, and, I will appreciate very much an explanation as well!

Comment: @Divakar Ok, I understand the expansion of `x` to the third dimension, this is because of the `dim` of `A`, right? And in the second line you are taking a `mapping` back to the desired `dim`. But, if I change the numbers `[3 1 2]` to any other order would the code still work? you have `[1 3 2]` in your second line(!)? and regarding the second line: what does `size(val,3)` and `[]` do?

Comment: Thanks guys! I was worried I had posted a very boring question...(may be it is) but I have learn very much this hour!!!

Comment: @Divakar Nice use of `bsxfun`

Comment: @Divakar What if my `A` is of `dim` 1 000? and not `3D`? how would this affect the code?

Comment: @SergioHaram You kidding me? Its a great question! So, regarding your doubts, yes extended `x` to third dimension because `A` is 2D and it won't work if you change `[3 1 2]` to anything else. On the second line, I did `permute [1 3 2]` to make the column elements in the third dimension come into consecutive indices when linearly indexed and rest is reshaping into the desired size.

Comment: @SergioHaram `A` is 1 000? What's that `000`?

Comment: @Divakar sorry I didn't explain my self clear. What happen if my matrix `A` is `(1000x1000)` and my vector `x` is (500x1) (just as an example), the singleton would be out of `dim` if I just have three variables `(3 1 2)` in the `val = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(x,[3 1 2]))` or am I wrong?

Comment: I am just trying to understand how can I take your code to higher dimensions.

Comment: You know @Divakar, never mind!!! I understand now how silly was my last question!

Comment: @SergioHaram If `A` is (1000x1000), it's still 2D and as such the posted code would work.

Comment: Yes, I just realize that :D sorry!

Comment: @SergioHaram haha it's all great!

Comment: @Divakar Amazing! Thank you so much, I will use this trick from now on to compute custom matrix multiplications (aka Generalized Matrix Product).

Comment: @user1121352 Yes `bsxfun` is indeed a great tool and if you are interested in multidimensional array  multiplication, you can use `bsxfun` there too. [This problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943842/multiplication-of-two-arrays-with-dimension-5-in-a-vectorize-way) talks about it, take a look!

Answer (score 10):

The [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function does exactly that:

```
kron(x.',A)
```

Comment: The `Kronecker product`(!) nice @Luis Mendo!

Comment: Thanks guys! I was worried I had posted a very boring question...(may be it is) but I have learn very much this hour!!!

Comment: @Divakar Yes, great tool. If you ever need to do the same with, say, sums instead of products, take a look at `kron`'s code: it uses `meshgrid` to generate all combinations, and not much more

Answer (score 3):

Here is my benchmark of the methods mentioned so far, along with a few additions of my own:

```
function [t,v] = testMatMult()
    % data
    %{
    x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
    A = [11 14 1; 5 8 18; 10 8 19; 13 20 16];
    %}
    x = 1:50;
    A = randi(100, [1000,1000]);

    % functions to test
    fcns = {
        @() func1_repmat(A,x)
        @() func2_bsxfun_3rd_dim(A,x)
        @() func2_forloop_3rd_dim(A,x)
        @() func3_kron(A,x)
        @() func4_forloop_matrix(A,x)
        @() func5_forloop_cell(A,x)
        @() func6_arrayfun(A,x)
    };

    % timeit
    t = cellfun(@timeit, fcns, 'UniformOutput',true);

    % check results
    v = cellfun(@feval, fcns, 'UniformOutput',false);
    isequal(v{:})
    %for i=2:numel(v), assert(norm(v{1}-v{2}) < 1e-9), end
end

% Amro
function B = func1_repmat(A,x)
    B = repmat(x, size(A,1), 1);
    B = bsxfun(@times, B(:), repmat(A,numel(x),1));
end

% Divakar
function B = func2_bsxfun_3rd_dim(A,x)
    B = bsxfun(@times, A, permute(x, [3 1 2]));
    B = reshape(permute(B, [1 3 2]), [], size(A,2));
end

% Vissenbot
function B = func2_forloop_3rd_dim(A,x)
    B = zeros([size(A) numel(x)], 'like',A);
    for i=1:numel(x)
        B(:,:,i) = x(i) .* A;
    end
    B = reshape(permute(B, [1 3 2]), [], size(A,2));
end

% Luis Mendo
function B = func3_kron(A,x)
    B = kron(x(:), A);
end

% SergioHaram & TheMinion
function B = func4_forloop_matrix(A,x)
    [m,n] = size(A);
    p = numel(x);
    B = zeros(m*p,n, 'like',A);
    for i=1:numel(x)
        B((i-1)*m+1:i*m,:) = x(i) .* A;
    end
end

% Amro
function B = func5_forloop_cell(A,x)
    B = cell(numel(x),1);
    for i=1:numel(x)
        B{i} = x(i) .* A;
    end
    B = cell2mat(B);
    %B = vertcat(B{:});
end

% Amro
function B = func6_arrayfun(A,x)
    B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(xx) xx.*A, x(:), 'UniformOutput',false));
end
```

The results on my machine:

```
>> t
t =
    0.1650    %# repmat (Amro)
    0.2915    %# bsxfun in the 3rd dimension (Divakar)
    0.4200    %# for-loop in the 3rd dim (Vissenbot)
    0.1284    %# kron (Luis Mendo)
    0.2997    %# for-loop with indexing (SergioHaram & TheMinion)
    0.5160    %# for-loop with cell array (Amro)
    0.4854    %# arrayfun (Amro)
```

*(Those timings can slightly change between different runs, but this should give us an idea how the methods compare)*

Note that some of these methods are going to cause out-of-memory errors for larger inputs (for example my solution based on `repmat` can easily run out of memory). Others will get significantly slower for larger sizes but won't error due to exhausted memory (the `kron` solution for instance).

I think that the `bsxfun` method `func2_bsxfun_3rd_dim` or the straightforward for-loop `func4_forloop_matrix` (thanks to MATLAB JIT) are the best solutions in this case.

Of course you can change the above benchmark parameters (size of `x` and `A`) and draw your own conclusions :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative, you maybe can use cellfun to achieve what you want. Here's an example (slightly modified from yours):

```
x = randi(2, 5, 3)-1;
a = randi(3,3);
%// bsxfun 3D (As implemented in the accepted solution)
val = bsxfun(@and, a, permute(x', [3 1 2])); %//'
out = reshape(permute(val,[1 3 2]),size(val,1)*size(val,3),[]);
%// cellfun (My solution)
val2 = cellfun(@(z) bsxfun(@and, a, z), num2cell(x, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);
out2 = cell2mat(val2); % or use cat(3, val2{:}) to get a 3D matrix equivalent to val and then permute/reshape like for out
%// compare
disp(nnz(out ~= out2));
```

Both give the same exact result.

For more infos and tricks using cellfun, see: http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/computation-using-cellfun/

And also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746422/1121352

Answer (score 0):

If your vector x is of lenght = 12 and your matrix of size 3x4, I don't think that using one or the other would change much in term of time. If you are working with higher size matrix and vector, now that might become an issue.

So first of all, we want to multiply a vector with a matrix. In the for-loop method, that would give something like that :

```
s = size(A);
new_matrix(s(1),s(2),numel(x)) = zeros;   %This is for pre-allocating. If you have a big vector or matrix, this will help a lot time efficiently.

for i = 1:numel(x)
    new_matrix(:,:,i)= A.*x(i)
end
```

This will give you 3D matrix, with each 3rd dimension being a result of your multiplication. If this is not what you are looking for, I'll be adding another solution which might be more time efficient with bigger matrixes and vectors.

Comment: thanks a lot! I indeed get the matrices I need but, I need only one `new_matrix` containing all the results I get when using your code. And yes, I am working with very big matrices, here, I have just given a simple example to make other understand my problem.

Comment: Yeah I noticed after when I saw Divakar answer! I misread and thought it was a 12xNxM matrix, and not 12*NxM! Divakar answers seems pretty neat to me!