# Vector times Matrix - Two cases

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a vector row `b = [b1 b2 b3 b4]` and a Matrix `M = [m1 m2 m3 m4]` where the m1,m2,m3 and m4 are column vectors of size N.

I want to do perform a multiplication so that I can have the following result in Matlab:
`Result = [b1*m1 b2*m2 b3*m3 b4*m4]`

and also, what if `B = [b11 b12 b13; b21 b22 b23;b31 b32 b33 b34;b41 b42 b43 b44]`  How would I get:

```
Result2 = [b11*m1 + b12*m2 + b13*m2;
           b21*m1 + b22*m2 + b23*m2;
           b31*m1 + b32*m2 + b33*m2;
           b41*m1 + b42*m2 + b43*m2]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: b1, b2, b3, b4 are scalars whereas m1,m2,m3 and m4 are column vectors of size N.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly:

```
bsxfun(@times,m,b)
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for this and perfect for `bsxfun`. +1

Comment: thanks Divkar, I guess the bsxfun will be a bit faster than matrix multiplication and diag...

Comment: yeah I mean the first problem seems like tailor-made for `bsxfun`, but still would be nice to some benchmarks if any working alternative solution is provided.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, I think [natan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896880/3293881) fits there perfectly.

For the second problem -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@times,[M(:,1) M(:,2) M(:,2)],permute(B,[3 2 1]))
Result2 = sum(reshape(permute(t1,[1 3 2]),size(t1,1)*size(t1,3),[]),2)
```

If you need the final result to be in Nx4 size, use this - `reshape(Result2,[],4)`.

**Note:** One very similar question that might be interesting to you - [`bsxfun implementation in matrix multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: @user5503 Sorry I must have put the `sum` there. Edited! You expect `Result2` to be of `(4*N)x1` right?

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted the result to be N by 4 matrix?

Comment: @user5503 `reshape(Result2,[],4)`

Comment: @user5503 You are welcome and glad it worked for you!

Comment: @user5503 Let me suggest you to look into this question as it is very close to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication All these info are edited into the solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `diag` function to create a diagonal matrix that you can use to post-multiply your matrix:

```
M*diag(b)
```