# Matlab: Extend a matrix by extending its vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a `d`x`m`x`n` matrix `A` (interpretation: for each `n`, there are `m` vectors of dimension `d`). I would like to extend each d-dimensional vector as follows:

Consider a vector `v` of dimension d: (1,2,...,d) (it's (x_1,x_2,...,x_d) but I removed the 'x_' for simplicity). The goal is to extend `v` to obtain a `d*d` vector of the form:

(1,1,...,1,2,...,2,...,d,d,...,d)

Could anybody please suggest me a fast way to do that? (I guess that using a loop and extending each vector at each iteration is very slow.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Damn!

```
reshape(permute(repmat(permute(A,[1 4 2 3]),[1 d]),[ 2 1 3 4]),d*d,m,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reshape(A(ceil(1/d:1/d:numel(A))), d^2,m,n)
```