# Multiplication of two arrays with dimension=5 in a vectorize way

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a three dimensional domain in MATLAB. For each point in the domain I have defined three arrays of size `(NX,NY,NZ)` at each point of the domain:

```
A1; % size(A1) = [NX NY NZ]
A2; % size(A2) = [NX NY NZ]
A3; % size(A3) = [NX NY NZ]
```

For each element, I am trying to construct an array which holds the value of `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`. Would the following be a good candidate for having a `1×3` vector at each point?

```
B = [A1(:) A2(:) A3(:)];
B = reshape(B, [size(A1) 1 3]);
```

If the `1×3` array is named `C`, I am trying to find `C'*C` at each point.

```
C = [A1(i,j,k) A2(i,j,k) A3(i,j,k)]; % size(C) = [1 3]
D = C'*C; % size(D) = [3 3]
```

My ultimate goal is to find the array `D` with size `3×3` for all the points in the domain in a vectorize fashion? In fact, the output which consists of array D for each point will have the size `[NX NY NZ 3 3]`. Could someone help me?

Comment: I don't think MATLAB can perform matrix operations (e.g. matrix-matrix multiplication or transpose operation) on more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: some FEX options: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8773-multiple-matrix-multiplications--with-array-expansion-enabled , http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515-mmx-multithreaded-matrix-operations-on-n-d-matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we concatenate `A1`, `A2` and `A3` along the 4th and 5th dimensions separately that leaves singleton dimensions in the 5th and 4th dimensions respectively, which are then used by [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) [*Apply element-by-element binary operation to two arrays with singleton expansion enable*] to expand as `3x3 matrices` along the 4th-5th dimensions for matrix multiplication result from each triplet of `[A1(i,j,k),A2(i,j,k),A3(i,j,k)]`.

```
D = bsxfun(@times,cat(4,A1,A2,A3),cat(5,A1,A2,A3));
```

Comment: I am trying to understand it perfectly as `bsxfun` has been always confusing for me. My understanding is that since the 5th and 4th dimension of `bsxfun` arguments are singleton, therefore `@times` will be applied on the 4th and 5th dimension of the each arguments, leaving the rest of dimensions intact. The 4th and 5th dimension of `cat(4,A1,A2,A3)` has a size `[3 1] ` and that of `cat(5,A1,A2,A3)` has a size `[1 3]`, `@times` multiplies these two to result in a `3×3` matrix for each non singleton element. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @A2009 You nailed it! Good job on getting it right with you! I like your explanation.