# MATLAB: element-wise multiplication of two matrices over one index?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I'm trying to figure out if there's a native way of obtaining a certain kind of element-wise product of two matrices in Matlab.

The product that I'm looking for takes two matrices, `A` and `B` say, and returns there product `C`, whose elements are given by

```
C(i,j,k) = A(i,j)*B(j,k)
```

Naturally, the number of columns of `A` is assumed be the same as the number of rows of `B`.

Right now, I'm using the following for-loop (assuming `size(A,2)==size(B,1)` is true). First, I initialize `C`:

```
C = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2), size(B,2));
```

And then I perform element-wise multiplication via:

```
for i=1:size(A,2)
    C(:,i,:) = A(:,i)*B(i,:);
end
```

So, my question is: **Is there a native way to this sort of thing in Matlab?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "shift" the first two dimensions of B into second and third dimensions respectively with **[`permute`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)** and then use **[`bsxfun` with `@times` option](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** to operate on `A` and the shifted dimension version of `B` -

```
C = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3 1 2]))
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on permuting a 2D array with a 3D permutation vector?

Comment: @Kris If you are talking about permutation matrix, that's a different ball-game. Think of permute in this case as more of a reshaping thing. So, with `permute(B,[3 1 2])`, I am making columns of it as rows and the rows as the slices in 3D. After that, with `bsxfun(@times..)`, the expansion of elements takes place to cover for the singleton dimensions for both `A` and the shifted version of B and finally the elementwise multiplication. Hope this makes sense? Looking into the linked documentations of these two functions should make it more clear.

Comment: @Kris Here's one very closely related one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication/23808285#23808285 , might be worth a look!