# Efficient element wise function on two matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have two matrices A and B and I want to perform an element wise maximum on them. I just wrote the following code which is very inefficient and takes a long time to run.

```
A = C;
for x = 1 : height
    for y = 1 : width
        if(A(x, y) < B(x, y))
            A(x, y) = B(x, y);
        end
    end
end
```

I searched SO and figured out that similar questions have been answered using `bsxfun` function ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192800/matlab-efficient-vectorized-way-to-apply-function-on-two-matrices), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911670/efficiently-compute-pairwise-squared-euclidean-distance-in-matlab), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831564/matlab-element-wise-multiplication-of-two-matrices-over-one-index)). But I could not get the point.

can `bsxfun` be applied here too?

What I want would be something like `A = max(B, C)`.

Comment: Isn't `max(A,B)` what you want? From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html): _MAX(X,Y) returns an array the same size as X and Y with the
    largest elements taken from X or Y. Either one can be a scalar._

Comment: Your code would take the minimum anyway, because when A > B you assign something smaller.

Comment: @ Pieter21 thank you I corrected it

Comment: @Luis Mendo yes you are right I was overthinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bsxfun(@(x,y) x<y,A,B)
```

Will return the indexes where A>B.

So :

```
A(bsxfun(@(x,y) x<y,A,B))=B(bsxfun(@(x,y) x<y,A,B));
```

Should do the trick.

But no need to use bsxfun, you can just go :

```
A(A<B)=B(A<B);
```

Or just use max (shame on me) as stated in the comments

Comment: you can do the comparison in the last one once and use it on the arrays to shave more time.

Comment: although I was overthinking, your answer to this question is right and very helpful on understanding the `bsxfun` functionality, thanks