# Obtain 3-D matrix from multiplication of one 1-D matrix and one 2-D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I want to something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3;4,5,6]
```

Then,

```
a *some operation* b = 
[1,2,3;4,5,6] 
[2,4,6;8,10,12]
[3,6,9;12,15,18]
```

Each element of matrix *a* is multiplied with all the elements matrix *b* and as many elements there are in *a* those many matrices are obtained as results. I don't want to use loops.

Comment: Use the first part of the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23808285/3293881) in that linked duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks. Got just what I wanted.