# Can I find common values between each row of a matlab matrix and a vector without a loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `A = [a X b]` and a vector `Z = [1 X z]`, where `z > b`.

I want to find the indices of matrix `A` for which `Z` and each row of the matrix `A` have the same value. I know I can do this by applying [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to each row of `A`, but I would to find a faster solution without using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Let's [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) it -

```
squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(Z(:),[3 2 1])),2))
```

Or

```
any(bsxfun(@eq,permute(A,[1 3 2]),Z(:).'),3)
```

Verify results with a sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     3     9     3     1     6
     4     9     4     2     5
     1     6     8     6     5
     2     1     1     7     3
>> Z
Z =
     7     2     7     2     4     6     8
>> for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    out_loopy(ii,:) = ismember(Z,A(ii,:));
end
>> out_loopy
out_loopy =
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
>> squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(Z(:),[3 2 1])),2))
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
>> any(bsxfun(@eq,permute(A,[1 3 2]),Z(:).'),3)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful `bsxfun` tutorial sensei ;). Can you elaborate on the `[3 2 1]` within the `permute`? I think I get the rest.

Comment: @Adriaan That "sends" `Z` to the third dimension, so that eXpansion with `bsxfun` could take place. Sort of like in [`this case`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication/23808285#23808285).

Comment: Thank you for you response but I misspecified my question. I actually want to know the indices of Z for which Z and each row of A have common values. So I want the solution based on your example to be 4 x 7

Comment: @user42527 This `squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(Z(:),[3 2 1])),2))` should work then. Edited answer with it.