# Vectorized search for permutations (with repetitions) that contain given subpermutations (with repetitions)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sequence, permutation, vectorization

This question is can be viewed continuation/extension/generalization of a previous question of mine from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383795/efficient-search-for-permutations-that-contain-sub-permutations-via-array-operat).

**Some definitions:** I have a set of integers `S = {1,2,...,s}`, say `s = 20`, and two matrices `N` and `M` whose rows are finite sequences of numbers from `S` (i.e. permutations with possible repetitions), of order `n` and `m` respectively, where `1 <= n <= m`. Let us think of `N` as a collection of candidate sub-sequences for the sequences from `M`.

Example: `[2 3 4 3]` is a sub-sequence of `[1 2 2 3 5 4 1 3]` that occurs with *multiplicity* 2 (=in how many different ways one can find the sub-seq. in the main seq.), whereas `[3 2 2 3]` is not a sub-sequence of it. In particular, a valid sub-sequence by definition must preserve the order of the indices.

**Problem statement:**

**(P1)** For each row of `M`, obtain the number of sub-sequences of it, with multiplicity and without multiplicity, that occur in `N` as rows (it can be zero if none are contained in `N`);

**(P2)** For each row of `N`, find out how many times, with multiplicity and without multiplicity, it is contained in `M` as a sub-sequence (again, this number can be zero);

**Example:** Let `N = [1 2 2; 2 3 4]` and `M = [1 1 2 2 3; 1 2 2 3 4; 1 2 3 5 6]`. Then **(P1)** returns `[2; 3; 0]` for 'with multiplicities' and `[1; 2; 0]` for 'without multiplicities'. **(P2)** returns `[3; 2]` for 'with multiplicities' and `[2; 1]` without multiplicities.

**Order of magnitude:** `M` could typically have up to 30-40 columns and a few thousand rows, although I currently have `M` with only a few hundred rows and ~10 columns. `N` could be approaching the size of 
`M` or could be also much smaller.

**What I have so far:** Not much, to be honest. I believe I might be able to slightly modify my not-very-well-vectorized solution from my previous question to tackle permutations with repetitions, but I am still thinking on that and will update as soon as I have something working. But given my (lack of) experience so far, it would be in all likelihood very suboptimal :(

Thanks!

Comment: What about GPU?  Can we use gpuArrays here?

Comment: Yes, most happily whenever possible :)

Comment: In the (P1) example, why is the second result 1? Second row of M contains subsequences 1 2 2 and 2 3 4, so the result for that row should be 2?

Comment: Ah, thanks, sorry, it was a typo. I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry, shouln'd it be 3 (with multiplicities)? The subsequence 2 3 4 appears twice in 2nd row of M, right?

Comment: Indeed, and for (P2) as well :) Can't get my own examples right...

Comment: It's easy to make mistakes doing it by hand :-) I just wanted to make sure I was getting it correctly

Comment: Sorry for the delay, boys, I had not forgotten about the question :) I wish I could accept both answers. Even though I use `VChooseK` for much better performance than `nchoosek` and `uint8/16` for better memory management rather than the default `double`, given the order of magnitude specified above, something like `nchoosek(1:40,20)` quickly becomes impractical. So, in view of this I decided to select Divakar's answer. Having said that, it will take me some time to follow through the code of both answers

Comment: Was a tough question, but still very interesting! Going through your trend, I am already a bit scared of your next question! ;) But   looking forward to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Introduction :** Owing to the repetitions in the input data in each row, the combination finding process doesn't have the sort of `"uniqueness"` among elements which was exploited in your previous problem and hence the loops used here. Also, note that the `without multiplicity` codes don't use `nchoosek` and as such, I feel more optimistic about them for performance.

**Notations :**

```
p1wim -> P1 with multiplicity
p2wim -> P2 with multiplicity
p1wom -> P1 without multiplicity
p2wom -> P2 without multiplicity
```

**Codes :**

I. Code for P1, 2 with multiplicity

```
permN = permute(N,[3 2 1]);

p1wim(size(M,1),1)=0;
p2wim(size(N,1),1)=0;

for k1 = 1:size(M,1)
    d1 = nchoosek(M(k1,:),3);
    t1 = all(bsxfun(@eq,d1,permN),2);
    p1wim(k1) = sum(t1(:));
    p2wim = p2wim + squeeze(sum(t1,1));
end
```

II. Code for P1, 2 without multiplicity

```
eqmat = bsxfun(@eq,M,permute(N,[3 4 2 1])); %// equality matrix

[m,n,p,q] = size(eqmat); %// get sizes
inds = zeros(size(M,1),p,q); %// pre-allocate for indices array

vec1 = [1:m]'; %//' setup constants to loop
vec2 = [0:q-1]*m*n*p;
vec3 = permute([0:p-1]*m*n,[1 3 2]);

for iter = 1:p
    [~,ind1] = max(eqmat(:,:,iter,:),[],2);
    inds(:,iter,:) = reshape(ind1,m,1,q);
    ind2 = squeeze(ind1);
    ind3 = bsxfun(@plus,vec1,(ind2-1)*m); %//' setup forward moving equalities
    ind4 = bsxfun(@plus,ind3,vec2);
    ind5 = bsxfun(@plus,ind4,vec3);
    eqmat(ind5(:)) = 0;
end

p1wom = sum(all(diff(inds,[],2)>0,2),3);
p2wom = squeeze(sum(all(diff(inds,[],2)>0,2),1));
```

As usual, I would encourage you to use `gpuArrays` too with your favorite `parfor`.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. You are right, for the specified order of magnitude for `M` and `N`, the below usage of `nchoosek` could quickly make the code impossible, e.g. `nchoosek(1:40,20)`. In that regard, your `nchoosek` usage is much better behaved. Actually, I'd also replace it by `VChooseK` as the latter is much, much faster.

Comment: @July Didn't know about `VChooseK` until till point as I found it on MATLAB FEX. So, it appears to be MEXed, which is great and yeah might be helpful with performance. I dearly wished to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses only one loop over the rows of `M` (P1) or `N` (P2). The code makes use of [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and the very powerful [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function. Note that if the number of columns is large you may experience problems because of [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html).

```
[mr mc] = size(M);
[nr nc] = size(N);

%// P1
combs = nchoosek(1:mc, nc)-1;
P1mu = NaN(mr,1);
P1nm = NaN(mr,1);
for r = 1:mr
    aux = M(r+mr*combs);
    P1mu(r) = sum(ismember(aux, N, 'rows'));
    P1nm(r) = sum(ismember(unique(aux, 'rows'), N, 'rows'));
end

%// P2. Multiplicity defined to span across different rows
rr = reshape(repmat(1:mr, size(combs,1), 1),[],1);
P2mu = NaN(nr,1);
P2nm = NaN(nr,1);
for r = 1:nr
    aux = M(bsxfun(@plus, rr, mr*repmat(combs, mr, 1)));
    P2mu(r) = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, N(r,:), aux), 2));
    P2nm(r) = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, N(r,:), unique(aux, 'rows')), 2));
end

%// P2. Multiplicity defined restricted to within one row
rr = reshape(repmat(1:mr, size(combs,1), 1),[],1);
P2mur = NaN(nr,1);
P2nmr = NaN(nr,1);
for r = 1:nr
    aux = M(bsxfun(@plus, rr, mr*repmat(combs, mr, 1)));
    P2mur(r) = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, N(r,:), aux), 2));
    aux2 = unique([aux rr], 'rows'); %// concat rr to differentiate rows...
    aux2 = aux2(:,1:end-1); %// ...and now remove it
    P2nmr(r) = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, N(r,:), aux2), 2));
end
```

Results for your example data:

```
P1mu =
     2
     3
     0
P1nm =
     1
     2
     0
P2mu =
     3
     2
P2nm =
     1
     1
P2mur =
     3
     2
P2nmr =
     2
     1
```

Some optimizations to the code would be possible. Not sure they are worth the effort:

- Replace `repmat` by another `bsxfun` (using a 3rd dimension). That may save some memory
- Transpose original matrices and work down colunmns, instead of along rows. That may be faster.

Comment: Thanks! One question though: shouldn't `P2nm` be `[2; 1]` (since `[1 2 2]` occurs in two different rows) ?

Comment: @July I've corrected it. I keep the two approaches to P2: with multiplicity defined to span across different rows, or restricted to within one row

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when you allow multiplicity to span across different rows and don't count multiplicities, then a sub-sequence can occur at most 1 time (1 for "it's present in M somewhere" and 0 for "it's not present in M at all") ?

Comment: @July Yes, in that case the only possible results are 0 or 1